# Regex that matches a comma, and Alphabets only, including accented letters in .NET

Tags: regex, non-ascii-characters

I have a requirement that needs to validate an input field to only allow commas and alphabets (inlcuindg accented alphabets). Being a complete Regex Noob, I have no idea where to start. Can someone please shine some lights toward the right direction?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex, but I don't know .NET: `[,\w]+`